# Take snapshot of google map sdk (or any other library) in IOS without displaying map view and display in UIimageview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps, sdk

I want to take snapshot of google map from sdk ios library and store it as image locally and display in uiimageview .

Comment: Couldn't you just simply display the map and block user interactions on it?

Comment: no I need to display in uiimageview and share the image with other user

Answer (score 0):

You need take an screen shoot of your map view to do this you need put something like this

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.mapView.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
[self.mapView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

and then you can use img to show in UIImageView, Hope this helps you

Comment: It will work when I have map view to display . But I don't want to display any mapview  . how can it be done without displaying map view on screen ?

Comment: Did you test that?, I have some code on my app that use a UILabel without showing and it works perfect.